# Cuda 5.5 Toolkit (Windows) + MS Visual Studio requirement

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, nvidia

I'm helping someone with a new Windows 7 workstation that has two nVidia GPUs and see that MS Visual Studio is required for the complete Cuda 5.5 Toolkit to install properly.

Silly question: is Visual Studio not a free download? Also: there are many different versions of Visual Studio 2012, which should be installed?

Thanks in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio comes in free and non-free versions.

According to the CUDA 5.5 [release notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#windows-5-5), you need either the full version of Visual Studio 2012 or the free version, which is called [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products), and has some limitations compared to the full (paid) version.

You want the version of Visual Studio which is for Desktop use (which includes the C++ environment).

"Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop"